# How to join two jQuery event handlers together

Tags: jquery

I have two event handlers. One is a click handler and the other is a change handler. Besides the event selector the only difference is the assigning of a different variable to className.

Note: The entire code is not shown here.

**Event handler 1#:**

```
    $(document).on('change', '#selectContainer [id]', function () {
    prevClass = className;
    className = $("select").val();       <<<< DIFFERENT

    var back = '<div id="back"><div id="_'+ prevClass +'"></div></div>';

    link[prevClass] = original;
    original = link[className];
    link[className] += back;


       $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
           $('.inter').html(link[className]); 

           $('.inter').css({'background-image': 'url("' + className + '.png")'});
           $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 1.00);

       });
   });
```

**Event handler 2#:**

```
   $(document).on('click', '.inter [class], .inter #back [id]', function () {
   prevClass = className;
   className = (this.id || this.className).substr(1);      <<<< DIFFERENT


    var back = '<div id="back"><div id="_'+ prevClass +'"></div></div>';

    link[prevClass] = original;
    original = link[className];
    link[className] += back;


       $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
           $('.inter').html(link[className]); 

           $('.inter').css({'background-image': 'url("' + className + '.png")'});
           $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 1.00);

       });
   });
```

**ENTIRE CODE:**

```
/* Preload images function for speed*/

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $('body').addClass("loading");
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
    $('body').removeClass("loading");
}

function transformImage(className, original, link, prevClass) {
    var back = '<div id="back"><div id="_' + prevClass + '"></div></div>';

    link[prevClass] = original;
    original = link[className];

    link[className] += back;



    $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
        $('.inter').html(link[className]);


        $('.inter').css({
            'background-image': 'url("' + className + '.png")'
        });
        $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 1.00);

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Images to preload*/
    var preloadi = [
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/1.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/2.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/3.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/4.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/5.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/6.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/7.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/8.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/9.png',
        '/WCMSWR/_assets/images/10.png'];


    var prevClass = '0';
    var className = '0';
    var original = 'yresadfasxdsa';


    var link = ['<div class="_0"></div><div class="_22"></div><div class="_22t"><p>This is a tooltip. This is the first step for the jquery path system</p><div class="tooltiptail"></div></div>', // 0
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_3"></div><div class="_4"></div>', // 1
    '<div class="_0"></div><div id="selectContainer"><select id="select" name="select1"><option>Select option</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option></select></div>', // 2
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_5"></div><div class="_6"></div>', // 3
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_7"></div><div class="_8"></div>', // 4
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_23"></div><div class="_10"></div>', // 5
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_7"></div><div class="_11"></div>', // 6
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_24"></div><div class="_9"></div>', // 7
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_23"></div><div class="_10"></div>', // 8
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_25"></div>', // 9
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_12"></div><div class="_13"></div>', // 10
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_25"></div>', // 11
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_2"></div><div class="_13"></div>', // 12
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_14"></div><div class="_15"></div>', // 13
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 14
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_16"></div><div class="_17"></div>', // 15
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 16
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_18"></div><div class="_19"></div>', // 17
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 18
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_20"></div><div class="_21"></div>', // 19
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 20
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 21
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_1"></div><div class="_1t"><p>This is a tooltip. This is the first step for the jquery path system</p><div class="tooltiptail"></div></div><div class="_2"></div>', // 22
    '<div class="_0"></div>', // 23
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_7"></div><div class="_11"></div>', // 24
    '<div class="_0"></div><div class="_12"></div><div class="_13"></div>' // 25
    ];

    /* If you wish to insert tooltips use the below template code

<div class="_22t"><p>This is a tooltip. This is the first step for the jquery path system</p><div class="tooltiptail"></div></div>

*/

    preload(preloadi);

    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function (event) {
        $('.' + this.className + 't').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#selectContainer [id]', function () {
    alert(original);
    prevClass = className;
    className = $("select").val();
    transformImage(className, original, link, prevClass); // call the method to do the image processing
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.inter [class], .inter #back [id]', function () {
    prevClass = className;
    className = (this.id || this.className).substr(1);
    transformImage(className, original, link, prevClass); // call the method to do the image processing
    })


})
```

**SIDE NOTE:**

On a side note if I am using incorrect terminology or if I should change the structure of my posts please correct me as I am still learning. :)

Comment: you can try making a function that performs the routine then call the function in each event handle. I hope that will help you lessen the code. But it didn't actually solve your problem in joining two events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not to mix up combining the event handlers that too of different selectors, instead just move generic functionality to a common function that can be called. This will help you maintain different event as it is ans any modification required in future on any of these handlers will make it easier with this approach rather than again splitting them out later.

sometimes you don't want to make everything `DRY`.

```
$(function(){ //ready is not required if it is bound to document head
    $(document).on('change', '#selectContainer [id]', function () {
         prevClass = className;
         className = $("select").val();       <<<< DIFFERENT
         transformImage(className); // call the method to do the image processing
      }

     $(document).on('click', '.inter [class], .inter #back [id]', function () {
       prevClass = className;
       className = (this.id || this.className).substr(1);      <<<< DIFFERENT
       transformImage(className);// call the method to do the image processing
     }
  });
//Move out your generic piece of functionality to another method. Put it out side of document.ready.
function transformImage(className)
{
    var back = '<div id="back"><div id="_'+ prevClass +'"></div></div>';

    link[prevClass] = original;
    original = link[className];
    link[className] += back;


       $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {
           $('.inter').html(link[className]); 

           $('.inter').css({'background-image': 'url("' + className + '.png")'});
           $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 1.00);

       });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the above code a bit more? The function uses both the prevClass and className variables. Do they both need to be in the () LIKE: 
function transformImage(className, prevName)

Comment: Just updated the answer and comments on code, let me know if you still have any question.

Comment: See updated comment above. Also, why are the event handlers wrapped in the $(function() {} function? (I am new to this)

Comment: if event handlers are attached to any element then you need to wrap them under document ready so that when this event handler binding code executed the elements are availabel to bind and they will be available only after document is ready, if it is on document head as you are doing, you dont need it since it is available before the document is loaded.

Comment: Try not to attach event delegation to the document head as much as possible, instead attach it to the closest container that is guarantee d to exist in DOM.

Comment: So instead of document head do something like  $('inter').on ? (Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: yes $(function(){..}); is a shortcut. INstead of document you can use the container of `inter` that exists in the page all the time, as i believe inter is created dynamically right

Comment: I have placed the code in and I am getting an Unexpected token } error on line:   });

Comment: I fixed the above error. I am now getting an: prevClass is not defined error in the console.

Comment: You can pass in className and prevClassName as arguments. This is not a tested piece so could find the typos.. :)

Comment: @sephiith your previousClass and className, both are same. since you are assigning it in the first line itself. So you don't need both of them probably.

Comment: No problems. :) Do I pass the arguments in as function transformImage(className, prevClass, link[className])?

Comment: i think you may want to pass in just className and original. prevClass is same as className just that seems like yo uare using it only for swapping.

Comment: It still gives me the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: prevClass is not defined 

I have added my entire code with the changes to the post. :)

Comment: That got rid of the prevClass error but now there is: ReferenceError: link is not defined (link is an array)

Comment: Yeah move link next to where `original` is defined.

Comment: No ERRORS! But, the function doesn't seem to be updating the html. "$('.inter').html(link[className]);"

Comment: Debug and check if inter exist in that content and link[className] is actually what is required. also you can remove document ready wrapper over those `on` event handlers

Comment: I tracked it down. It seems like the value for the original variable isn't getting updated in the global scope. I am unsure what to do to fix it.

Comment: If it is under global script you should be able to access it right? but now your code is getting re factored...

Comment: I'm updating the code in the post now. I have confirmed the original variable in the global scope isn't updating.

Comment: If in global scope remove `var` and you can access it via window.original. Instead of keeping it there yo ucan also try to put it in localStorage cache or data of some element and access it. That will be better.